# Running a script from a Grunt template

Tags: gruntjs

Is it possible to run a script directly from a Grunt template? So when I do a

```
grunt-init grunt_template
```

have something like the following run

```
npm install
grunt task
git ....
```

My work involves lots of little 'projects' so it would be nice if I could get this all in one command. Thanks in advance for any help.